# FileNotFoundError when using subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, file-not-found

```
from subprocess import check_output
output=check_output(["ls", "F:\myData\input"]).decode("utf8")
print(ouptut)
```

I'm trying to run this code to view the files in this directory and save the results as output but this line is throwing an error upon execution.

Can anyone help me solve this and understand the issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\myData\input\Analysis.py", line 21, in <module>
    output=check_output(["ls", "F:\myData\input\Analysis.py]).decode("utf8")
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen for `check_output(['ls']).decode('utf8')`?

Comment: Yes i keep on getting the same error

Comment: `ls` isn't installed on your computer. You can either try to install it (I assume you're on windows), or you could try using the similar windows command `dir`: `output=check_output(["dir", "F:\myData\input"]).decode("utf8")`

Comment: Again, getting the same error